# Converting one parameter pack into another?

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, c++14

I would like to convert a parameter pack of iterator types into the corresponding parameter pack of references. This is what I've got so far:

```
template <class Iterator, class... Iterators>
class cast_iterators_to_references
{
    using head_reference_type = std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference

    // TODO
    //using type = ;
};
```

Where do I take it from here?

The reason I'm doing this is to create a "view" object. It contains a tuple of iterators to the containers it's referencing. I'd like to have a method that returns a tuple of the elements at some index so that I can create a custom iterator for it, create begin and end methods, and use it in a range-based for statement.

Here's how it could be used:

```
template<class Iterators...>
tuple_iterator
{
public:
    using tuple_type = std::tuple<Iterators...>;
    using references = cast_iterators_to_references<Iterators...>;
    using tuple_element_type = std::tuple<references>;

    // ... construct from tuple, copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment etc.

    tuple_element_type operator[](size_t index)
    {
        tuple_element_type element;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Iterators); i++)
            std::get<i>(element) = std::get<i>(data_)[offset_ + index];

        return element;
    }

    // ... increment, decrement operators etc.

private:
    tuple_type data_;
    size_t offset_;
}
```

Comment: you probably want `class... Iterators` instead of `class Iterators...`

Comment: How do you envision this to be used? Suppose you managed to implement `cast_iterators_to_references` to your liking - can you show what the client code using it is expected to look like?

Comment: What's the `pack` class you've used? Also, is using a `for` loop like above the best way to transform a tuple?

Comment: @Stefan see my answer. The `for`-loop is definitely not the way to go, as it son't even compile (`i` is not a constant expression). But I don't understand what exactly that operator does : iterators don't have an `operator[]`. What are you trying to access, and what is `index` ?

Comment: @Quentin Random access iterators have a `operator[]`. Yes about the `for` loop, but I'm not sure how to apply an operator to all elements of a tuple that unrolls the loop at compile time.

Comment: @Stefan oooh, that's new to me ! I'll have a go at a solution for that too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter packs are not first-class, so they are a bit fiddly to handle.

A first stab at the `cast_iterators_to_references` metafunction could be this :

```
// Not defined, used to wrap a pack into a type
template <class...> struct pack;

template <class... Iterators>
using cast_iterators_to_references = pack<
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterators>::reference...
>;
```

But then you need helper classes to unpack the `pack` via pattern-matching :

```
template <class> unpack_to_tuple;

template <class... Ts> unpack_to_tuple<pack<Ts...>> {
    using type = std::tuple<Ts...>;
};

// In your class
using references = cast_iterators_to_references<Iterators...>;
using tuple_element_type = typename unpack_to_tuple<references>::type;
```

So you're probably better off using the parameter pack directly :

```
using tuple_element_type = std::tuple<
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iterators>::reference...
>;
```

Your `operator[]` can be written as follows :

```
template <std::size_t... Idx>
auto access(size_t index, std::index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    return std::tie(std::get<Idx>(data_)[index + offset_]...);
}

tuple_element_type operator[](size_t index)
{
    return access(index, std::index_sequence_for<Iterators...>{});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin, I think the last line is what I'm looking for. I didn't realize you could apply a metafunction to every element in a parameter pack like that. I'll post a link to my complete solution in a bit.